# Count divs that are hidden

Tags: javascript, html, count, hidden, element

I need a vanilla JS way to count the number of hidden divs on a page.

I have three divs with inline styles `display: none`. I thought this would work, but no luck:

```
var hiddenContainers = (document.getElementsByClassName(".emp-container").style.display == "none").length;
```

I have tried several solutions from SO and found a few JQuery ones that were successful, but what I'm writing needs to be done exclusively in regular old JavaScript.

EDIT:  This works, but it seems like an unnecessarily roundabout way to get what I want:

```
var hiddenContainers = [];
  var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".emp-container");
  for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
    if (containers[i].style.display == "none") {
      hiddenContainers.push(containers[i]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your selector is targeting a group of elements (multiple) which will return a node list/collection so you must specify which element you are trying to target.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function countclick(){
  var m = document.querySelectorAll('.divs[style*="display:none;"]').length;
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "Hidden Divs: "+m;
}
```

```html
<div class='divs' style="display:none;">a</div>
<div class='divs' style="">b</div>
<div class='divs' style="">c</div>
<div class='divs' style="display:none;">d</div>
<div class='divs' style="">e</div>
<div class='divs' style="display:none;">f</div>
<hr/>
<span id="count">Hidden Divs: 0</span><br/>
<button onclick='countclick();'>Count</button>
```

Comment: Your solution is offering the same thing the OP would like to try avoid using.

Comment: I edited! See above code `var m = document.querySelectorAll('.divs[style*="display:none;"]').length;`

Comment: Very good, be sure to read the question carefully before submitting your solution. This can result in others down voting your post rather than up voting or making as correct.